# What is the equation of the line that "creates an intercept of $-8$ from the $x$-axis and makes an angle of $45^\circ$"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

*This question came in the Chittagong University admission exam 11-12*

> What is the equation of the line that creates an intercept of $-8$ from the $x$-axis and makes an angle of $45^\circ$?
>
> (a) $x+y+8=0$
>
> (b) $3x+8y=1$
>
> (c) $x-y=8$
>
> (d) $y=8$
>
> (e) $x=8$

**My attempt:**

I interpreted creates "an intercept of -8 from the x-axis and makes an angle of 45" meaning that the x-intercept is -8 and the slope is $\tan(45^{\circ})$.  According to this interpretation, the equation should be $x-y=-8$. None of the options have this equation. The closest one is (c), and the third-party question bank says that the correct answer is (c). Isn't (c) wrong?

Comment: (C) makes a -45-degree angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I shall attempt this question in the most technically reasonable way, which may differ from the setter's intention.

> > What is the equation of the line that creates an intercept of $-8$ from the $x$-axis

This means some intercept of the line is displaced from the $x$-axis by $-8$ units, which means that the line has $y$-intercept $-8.$

(But who writes this way? Is this a Mathematics or English-language test?)

> > and makes an angle of $45^\circ$?

Going with the usual convention that the reference line is the positive $x$-axis and angles are measured anticlockwise, this means that the line's gradient is $\tan 45^\circ.$

Hence, the correct answer is indeed **(c)** $$x-y=8.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let the line equation be $y=kx+b$

Slope is $k=\tan(\pi/4)=1$

$$\Rightarrow y=x+b$$

Intercept on x-axis is $-8$ means it passes the point $A(-8,0)$, plug into the equation,

$$0=-8+b\Rightarrow b=8$$

Solution is $y=x+8$

----Alternative Candidate----

Maybe it takes the angle to be $135$ degree. (But usually we don't say it in this way.)

Slope is $k=\tan(3\pi/4)=-1$

$$\Rightarrow y=-x+b$$

Intercept on x-axis is $-8$ means it passes the point $A(-8,0)$, plug into the equation,

$$0=8+b\Rightarrow b=-8$$

Solution is $y=x-8$

Comment: But that option isn’t on the list. Good explanation though…

Comment: Right, maybe it takes $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ for the angle, but that's weird, usually we don't say it in that way...

Comment: This option isn't on the list.

Comment: Yes, I add the alternative solution, but usually we don't say it in this way.@tryingtobeastoic

Comment: The way I read the problem, it's the $x$-intercept that is $-8$ not the $y$-intercept.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to make a $45$ degree angle with the $x$-axis.  The other way is to have slope $-\tan 45^\circ.$  So option a works just fine.

Also, you get the $x$-intercept when $y=0$, so c can't be the correct answer.

Comment: Please elaborate…

Comment: @MathAndPhysics A line with slope $-1$ _also_ makes a $45^\circ$ angle with the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

It is a case of strange language.

Normally, we talk of intercepts **with** an axis, here it says intercept of $-8$ **from** the X-axis. This can only mean that $y=-8$ when $x=0$,

and taking the normal anticlockwise meaning of $45^\circ$,
we get $y = x -8 \; \Rightarrow\; x-y = 8\;$ ie alternative $(c)$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (c), because the question says that the intercept is $-8$ from the x-axis, or that the y-intercept is $-8$. Since the x-axis is $y=0$, this means the intercept with the y-axis is $y=-8$. So, since the tangent of $\pi/4$ is $1$, the slope is $1$. We get:$$y=x-8$$Or,$$x-y=8$$